# Calling value inside a Userform's Control using a variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to call a value from a form to put it on SQL. But it doesn't work.

```
Dim n As integer
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim mymain As Variant
Dim inputform as string
mymain = Array("well_name", "well_alias", "well_short")

n=0
--try to loop
inputform="form_inputwell"+mymain(n)
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO databasewell (bh_name) VALUES ('" & inputform & "');"
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
n=n+1
--loop end
```

Any idea to call the value which field inside an array?
for example :

```
form_inputwell.well_name called by declaring "form_inputwell"+mymain(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution, but thanks anyway for helping.

```
paramtemp = Forms("form name").Controls(field in form).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you are trying to do :

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim mymain As Variant
Dim inputform As String
mymain = Array("well_name", "well_alias", "well_short")

For n = LBound(mymain) To UBound(mymain)
    inputform = form_inputwell.Controls(mymain(n)).Value
    StrSQL = "INSERT INTO databasewell (bh_name) VALUES ('" & inputform & "');"
    DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
Next n
```

Comment: by your code, the inputform is still "form_inputwell.well_name" i think. What I want is the value of form_inputwell.well_name.

Comment: Ok! So in facts, you need the value inside of the control called `well_name`? Give the edit a try! ;)